# How to select only the first groups of a string between white space? [Python]

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hi I'm cleaning up a bigdata about food products and I'm struggling with one columns `types(df['serving_size']=O)` that informs about the size of the product. It's a pandas dataframe that contains 300.000 observations. I succeeded to clean the text that was included with the size with helps of `Regex`:

```
df['serving_size'] = df['serving_size'].str.replace('[^\d\,\.]', ' ')
df['serving_size'] = df['serving_size'].str.replace('(^\d\,\.+)\s', '')
```

And I got this (the space are White Space)

```
40.5   23
       13
87            23
   123
72,5
```

And my goals would be to keep only the first group of numbers for each rows including the `,`and `.` like so:

```
40.5
13
87
123
72.5
```

Despite my reserch I didn't find how to achieve it ? Thanks

Comment: Try something like this str.replace(" ","\n") just add \n in the second argument to str.replace

Comment: Maybe [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex like `^(?:\s+)?(\d+(?:\.|,)?\d+?)` Example: https://regex101.com/r/3BBi88/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex, as follows:

```
df['serving_size'] = df['serving_size'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  serving_size
0         40.5
1           13
2           87
3          123
4         72.5
```